# Is there a benefit of a second index if column is already part of other index?

Tags: mysql

I have a MysQL 5.7 table with about 500m records with a unique index on (column1, column2, column3, date).

In some cases I only query for records from a particular day. e.g. DATE = curdate() - interval 2 day. This can take up to 1 minute.

Would there be a benefit if there would be a seperate index on date?

Comment: Does your unique index is used for uniqueness checking only, or it improves a lot of non-listed queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point to appreciate here is that for queries *only* involving the `date` column, MySQL would not be able to use your current 4-column index.  The reason for this is that B-tree splits on 3 other columns before hitting the `date` column.  As a result, this index could only satisfy the date query if MySQL were to do a complete index scan.  Typically, in this case, MySQL would just rather do a full table scan and not bother with the index.

So, if you want your date filter only query to use an index, you would have to add a new index:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx2 ON yourTable (date);
```

Regarding index "bloat," namely having too many indices, you are not really near that with just 2 indices defined.  If you do find that you have say 5-7 indices defined, then you might be able to combine or consolidate them.

Comment: @merlin Or just change the order of the existing index, if appropriate

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Funny engough I had a second index on my dev server but not on the prod server.

Comment: @merlin Regarding the final part of my answer, read the comment by Strawberry above.  If you can accept it, you could just move the `date` column to the front of the 4-column index.  But, if you can't accept that, then you'd need to create a new index.

Comment: Good point. I am not sure as I need to check all queries if they depend on date. Most of them filter on column1, column2, date I believe.

Comment: @merlin So the issue then is which column do you want to use to filter first.  Typically, you would place columns which are more restrictive earlier in the index.

Comment: The table consists out of data for 10 merchants. Each having 300K records per day. A typical query is: Get me the data for merchant x of day y. That is why merchant_id is first in the index.